# hasValidator function does not work with Validators.compose in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

in reactive form hasValidator functions does not work when use with Validators.compose

I want to display "*" if the formcontroller is required

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [
      '',
      Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.max(3)]),
    ],
    lastName: [''],
  });

  isFieldMandatory(name: string) {
    return (
      this.profileForm.get(name)?.hasValidator(Validators.required) ?? false
    );
  }
}
```

```
<fieldset>
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    <label for="first-name"
      >First Name: <span *ngIf="isFieldMandatory('firstName')">*</span></label
    >
    <input id="first-name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <span>
      {{ profileForm.get('firstName').errors | json }}
    </span>
    <br />

    <label for="last-name"
      >Last Name: <span *ngIf="isFieldMandatory('lastName')">*</span>
    </label>
    <input id="last-name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
    <span>
      {{ profileForm.get('lastName').errors | json }}
    </span>
  </form>
</fieldset>
<p>Form Status: {{ profileForm.status }}</p>
```

Comment: This may not directly solve your current problem. Have you consider to replace `Validators.compose([...])` with an array (`[Validators.required, Validators.max(3)]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validators.compose() Compose multiple validators into a single function that returns the union of the individual error maps for the provided control

so validation array should change as follows

```
 profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [
      '',
      [Validators.required, Validators.max(3)],
    ],
    lastName: [''],
  });
```

if you really want to use Validators.compose()

```
 isFieldMandatory(name: string) {
          return this.profileForm.get(name)?.errors?.required ?? false; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a change in the isFieldMandatory function.
see the below changes...

```
     isFieldMandatory(name: string) {
          return this.profileForm.get(name)?.errors?.required ?? false; <--- Changes here only
    }
```

Explanations:-

you need to check if your form control has any error and if yes then check it with the error name like **required**.

required is the validation name, if you console log only this return `this.profileForm.get(name)?.errors` then you are getting all the errors/validations of your form control.

Stackblitz demo link --->
[Example demo link](https://angular-ivy-y6vskb.stackblitz.io)